# Getting SQLite DB data in 2d array and returning in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite

I have the below function which I use to query the SQLite Db, put the retrieved records in to an array and return it back.

```
public String[][] getrecords(){

    Log.i("SENDSERVER", "Get Records Called");
    SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT id,welawa,lati,longi FROM " +
        TABLE_LOCATIONS + " LIMIT 5", null);
    String[][] aryDB = new String[5][4];
    int i = 0;
    if (c != null ) {
        if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String db_id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
                String welawa = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("welawa"));
                String latitude = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lati"));
                String longitude = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("longi"));
                aryDB[i][0] = db_id;
                aryDB[i][1] = welawa;
                aryDB[i][2] = latitude;
                aryDB[i][3] = longitude;
                Log.i("SENDSERVER", "Record Added"); //This doesn't get logged
                i++;
           }while (c.moveToNext());
         } 
    }
    Log.i("SENDSERVER", "Return Records");
    return aryDB;

}
```

I try to retrieve the records and use them as below from my service class.

```
String aryDB[][] = dbh.getrecords();
Log.i("SENDSERVER", "GET DB RECORDS");
int i = 0;
int id = 0;
String welawa = "";
String lati = "";
String longi = "";
while(i < 5){
    id = Integer.parseInt(aryDB[i][0]);
    welawa = aryDB[i][1];
    lati = aryDB[i][2];
    longi = aryDB[i][3];
    Log.i("SENDSERVERDB", id + " - " + welawa + " - " + lati + " - " + longi);
    i++;
}
```

For some reason the array is not being returned.
My possible guesses are,
1. The defining of the function is wrong. My intention is to return the array.
2. I am getting the db connection / my retrieval code is wrong.
3. Some thing else that my noob brain can't comprehend.

Your help is greatly appreciated guys.

------EDIT
After adding some more logs the app crashes at

```
Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT id,welawa,lati,longi FROM " +
                TABLE_LOCATIONS + " LIMIT 5", null);
```

Any issue in my query?

Comment: Do you have records really fetched? Any errors or anything? Generally, you should create a `Pojo` object for every record and add them to a list and return the list. Working with arrays will be difficult in this scenario for me

Comment: When i do a record count I have about 300 records. Just trying to get 5. I added a Log before the "i++" in me retrieval function. Doesnt get logged.

Comment: Where in the `do-while` or `while` loop? If you are not able to print the logs while iterating the records, then you have problem in the record fetching

Comment: in the do-while. Yup I am lead to believe so too. Any idea? Newbie to android coding.

Comment: I think your cursor is `null`. Check `sampleDB.rawQuery` whether it returns the Cursor instance

Comment: I have "if (c != null ) {" in the coding. If so, wouldnt it still return the array empty?

Comment: yes, it will return it empty with all indexes as `null`

Comment: so I added a few logs. The app gets stuck at Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT id,welawa,lati,longi FROM " +
    TABLE_LOCATIONS + " LIMIT 5", null); .

Comment: You have to check your query first and test it, then use it in the code

Comment: The Cursor never returns null when there is no row which the requested conditions, just return a empty Cursor.

Comment: thanks you two. Seems like I misspelled a column name. I just wished the error messages would be easier. It can say "You column couldnt be found" like php or vb. lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a DB issue. Wrong ColumnName used.

Answer (score 0):

The Cursor never returns null when there is no row which the requested conditions, just return a empty Cursor.

You code still has problem when the rawQuery returns 0 rows, cursor won't be null and do while loop will execute at least once. 
So there will be problem on this line when the cursor is empty

```
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
```

Change your code to this:

```
c.moveToFirst();
while (c.moveToNext())
          {
                String db_id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
                String welawa = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("welawa"));
                String latitude = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lati"));
                String longitude = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("longi"));
                aryDB[i][0] = db_id;
                aryDB[i][1] = welawa;
                aryDB[i][2] = latitude;
                aryDB[i][3] = longitude;
                Log.i("SENDSERVER", "Record Added"); //This doesn't get logged
                i++;
           }
```